# Book that explores cryofreeze, before storing human DNA in threads becomes viable

Tags: story-identification, novel, cryogenics

I read this around 2005 from my high school library, though the book appeared at minimum a decade older.

The protagonist was one of few people who were successfully restored from cryofreeze, and he and another female are returned to normal life several hundreds of years after they were frozen.

Humans essentially don’t live on Earth anymore as satellites created or exposed some sort of brain borne virus. Thus, what remain of humans live on orbiting colonies, sparsely populated and usually by a scientist. That caveat is that humans are predominantly stored as genetic material in threads.

Our protagonists are with a psychotic scientist who clones himself with varying types of copies, one specifically intended to ‘experiment’ on the female with. He also likes to bring one character back to life after repeated suicides.

A last major part of the book was this alien-like female, what amounted to a disembodied consciousness, that was looking to merge with a human and would make both stronger, yet stranger.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hello! I used single quotes to poorly indicate paraphrasing. I don’t believe brain bore is the specific terminology, just vaguely recollect the condition was a horrific neurological disorder in which something akin to a virus forcibly entered the brain.

Comment: Noted, thank you!

Comment: @Adam - Someone using a new account has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, please merge your new account with the one you used to post this question by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.